# How to pass a parent to a QMessage subclass

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, subclass, super, qmessagebox

How can I properly pass the parent to the `QMessgaeBox` subclass? If I don't use the parent, the messagebox doesn't appear at the center of the window!

```
class onCloseMessage(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self):
        QMessageBox.__init__(self, QMessageBox.Question, "title", "message",
                             buttons= QMessageBox.Close)

dlg = onCloseMessage()
dlg.exec()
```

When I pass a parent, and replace `self` in the `__init__` by the parent, it gives errors. If I use `super`, how can I then `__init__` the QMessageBox?

I tried:

```
class onCloseMessage(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        QMessageBox.__init__(self, QMessageBox.Question, "title", "message",
                             buttons= QMessageBox.Close)
```

But, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `super`, you shouldn't call the base-class `__init__` as well. Instead, pass all the required arguments to `super` itself, like this:

```
class onCloseMessage(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(QMessageBox.Question, "title", "message",
                         buttons=QMessageBox.Close, parent=parent)
```

(NB: you can use Python keyword arguments wherever the [Qt signature](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#QMessageBox-1) shows default arguments).

Comment: Thanks for the great note of `Qt signature`